# QtCreator and "Run CMake"

Tags: c++, cmake, qt-creator

When running CMake from the project view in QtCreator ("Run CMake" command), CMake wizard pops up. This is becoming really annoying and since I'm QtCreator newbie, I don't know if there is any remedy for this.

Desired effect would be automatic execution of cmake, without the CMake wizard pestilence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this GUI annoying me too.

The only option is to add custom build step in your Project configuration

run app: cmake
params CMakeLists.txt
working folder: %{sourceDir}

this step should be added BEFORE make step.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have created a project in Qt Creator, you do not need to use the "Run CMake" command unless for some reason you think the project files are out of date. Just click build, run, debug etc and it will take care of compiling the files that need to be compiled and invoking CMake as and when necessary.

Underneath it uses Unix Makefiles with Codeblocks in order to generate an XML description of the project. Running CMake from the menu explicitly re-runs CMake and reparses the XML description.